# Can I put apps made on Corona SDK for windows on IOS?

Tags: coronasdk

I was just reading that the corona sdk for windows only builds for android devices.

So for us PC owners will we be at a disadvantage if we want to develop for IPADs or is there a way around this?

Can we work on the PC and then transfer the project to a mac to build it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer your projects to a Mac to build.  Many people use the Macincloud service for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can test your apps developed for Ipad,iphone ect... on Corona simulator on your PC. However, when you want to test the apps on the actual device, you need a Mac and a developer account with Apple.

Comment: So to your question, yes you can work on the PC and then transfer the project to the Mac before you can build it for the actual device.